# Weird React state behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a React project, and have run into an annoying bug. I have isolated the problem in the code below:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Variants = ({ variants, setVariants }) => {
  function toggleRemove(index) {
    setVariants((_variants) => {
      let newVariants = [..._variants];
      if (newVariants[index].action === "remove") {
        newVariants[index].action = undefined;
      } else {
        newVariants[index].action = "remove";
      }
      return newVariants;
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      {variants.map((variant, index) => (
        <div>
          <span>{variant.title}</span>
          <button onClick={() => toggleRemove(index)}>Toggle remove</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const AdminProductTools = ({ product }) => {
  const [variants, setVariants] = useState(product.variants);

  return (
    <div>
      <Variants variants={variants} setVariants={setVariants}></Variants>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(product)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Product = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    variants: [{ title: "dummy1" }, { title: "dummy2" }],
  });

  return <AdminProductTools product={product} />;
};

const App = () => {
  return <Product />;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

When I hit the 'Toggle remove' button next to a variant, I only expect the 'variants' state to change. Somehow the 'product' prop in AdminProductTools is being updated too (as seen in cyan span), even though 'setProduct' is never called.
Even weirder is, if you inspect Product in React DevTools, the 'product' state seems to update too, even though it is not reflected in the yellow span.

How can this be?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-haze-wk92e?file=/src/index.js

Comment: `newVariants[index].action = undefined;` mutates the state (and the prop). Don't mutate in React.

Comment: newVariants is not the state. It is a copy of the state, right? I do let newVariants = [..._variants]

Comment: Only a shallow copy. You need a deep copy.

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you!